# How to fail a (cron) job after a certain number of retries?

Tags: kubernetes

We have a Kubernetes cluster of web scraping cron jobs set up. All seems to go well until a cron job starts to fail (e.g., when a site structure changes and our scraper no longer works). It looks like every now and then a few failing cron jobs will continue to retry to the point it brings down our cluster. Running `kubectl get cronjobs` (prior to a cluster failure) will show too many jobs running for a failing job.

I've attempted following the note described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#pod-backoff-failure-policy) regarding a known issue with the pod backoff failure policy; however, that does not seem to work.

Here is our config for reference:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scrape-al
spec:
  schedule: '*/15 * * * *'
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scrape
        scrape: al
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: scrape-al
              image: 'govhawk/openstates:1.3.1-beta'
              command:
                - /opt/openstates/openstates/pupa-scrape.sh
              args:
                - al bills --scrape
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 3
```

Ideally we would prefer that a cron job would be terminated after N retries (e.g., something like `kubectl delete cronjob my-cron-job` after `my-cron-job` has failed 5 times). Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can tell your Job to stop retrying using `backoffLimit`.

> Specifies the number of retries before marking this job failed.

In your case

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: scrape-al
          image: 'govhawk/openstates:1.3.1-beta'
          command:
            - /opt/openstates/openstates/pupa-scrape.sh
          args:
            - al bills --scrape
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 3
```

You set 3 as`backoffLimit` of your Job. That means when a Job is created by CronJob, It will retry 3 times if fails. This controls Job, not CronJob

When Job is failed, another Job will be created again as your scheduled period.

**You want:**
If I am not wrong, *you want to stop scheduling new Job, when your scheduled Jobs are failed for 5 times*. Right?

**Answer:** 
In that case, *this is not possible automatically*.

**Possible solution:**
You need to [suspend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#suspend) CronJob so than it stop scheduling new Job.

```
Suspend: true
```

You can do this manually. If you do not want to do this manually, you need to setup a watcher, that will watch your CronJob status, and will update CronJob to suspend if necessary.

Comment: I think I understand a bit better now. So you're saying that on each cron job execution, I will reach the backoff limit, right? E.g., provided the job is failing, "Run 1" will have 3 failed attempts, "Run 2" will have another 3 failed attempts, and so on. Would there be any reason terminated pods (from these jobs) remain visible in the dashboard / `kubectl get pods`? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, Pods will be visible until Job is deleted. When Job will be deleted, Pods will be gone too.